# Ordenar por fecha en datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, date

Estoy intentando ordenar en una datatable por un campo de fecha pero no lo consigo.

He probado con varios plugins pero ninguno consigo que funcione correctamente.

El link de ejemplo es una simple datatable donde se supone que el campo 4 de fecha lo formatea a la fecha europea y deja ordenarla correctamente.

No se que falla.

http://live.datatables.net/jirukiga/2/edit?js,output

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: window.moment is not a function`. ¿Te falta agregar alguna biblioteca/fichero al ejemplo?

Comment: Arreglado. Le he añadido la libreria moment.js que sirve para tratar fechas. Ahora en el campo fecha me pone __invalid date__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

He utilizado la libreria [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) junto al plugin para datatables [datetime](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime).

a la hora de tratar las fechas

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
columnDefs: [ {
  targets: 4,
  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
} ]
```

} );

Donde la función **moment()** espera como parámetros un formato entrada y un formato de salida de fechas.

Con esto ordena las fechas correctamente y las muestra con cualquier formato

[Solución](http://live.datatables.net/jirukiga/5/edit?js,output).

Answer (score 1):

Veo que estas utilizando moment, pero en tu caso no creo que sea necesario porque la fecha esta en formato YYYY/MM/DD y de esta forma se ordenará correctamente ya que se ordena, por año, mes y día. ¿Qué hacer cuando la fecha tiene un formato diferente?... puedes recorrer cada element **tr** del **tbody** de la tabla, y tomar la fecha y colocarla en la celda dentro de un span que este no sea visible (display: none), en formato YYYYMMDD.

Ejemplo: http://live.datatables.net/sikuluvi/1/edit

**CSS**:

```
#example span {
    display:none; 
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
/* THIS IS ONLY FOR EXAMPLE TO CHANGE THE DATE FORMAT */
var changeDateFormat = $('#example tbody tr').each(function(i,e) {
  var dateTD = $(this).find('td:eq(4)');
  var date = dateTD.text().trim();
  var parts = date.split('/');
  dateTD.text(parts[0]+'/'+parts[2]+'/'+parts[1]);
});

$.when(changeDateFormat).done(function() {
  processDates(); 
})
/* THIS IS ONLY FOR EXAMPLE TO CHANGE THE DATE FORMAT */


function processDates() {
  var process = $('#example tbody tr').each(function(i,e) {
    var dateTD = $(this).find('td:eq(4)');
    var date = dateTD.text().trim();
    var parts = date.split('/');
    dateTD.prepend('<span>'+parts[0]+parts[2]+parts[1]+'</span>');
  });

  $.when(process).done(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({ "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]]});
  })
}
```